# How to set proper Current Population Survey surveyreplicate weight design?

Tags: r, survey

I am using the survey package and srvyr to explore the demographics of TANF recipients. I've used the package without problem for ACS microdata, but I am unable to set the survey replicate weight design for this CPS ASEC extract.

This is the call:

```
cpsasec_design <-
  svrepdesign(
    weights = ~ASECWT,
    repweights = "REPWTP[1-9]+", 
    type = "JK1", 
    scale = 4/60, 
    rscales = rep(1, 160), 
    mse = TRUE
  )
```

No matter how I adjust I still get this error:

```
Error in svrepdesign.default(data, weight = ~ASECWT, repweights = "REPWTP[1-9]+",  : 
  You must provide replication weights
```

I've tried multiple variations including including or not including the `+` sign, make the rang [0-9] etc...Has anyone else had an issue with the CPS in this way in R? What are some approaches or alternatives I should be taking?

Comment: http://asdfree.com/current-population-survey-annual-social-and-economic-supplement-cpsasec.html documents how to create the design

Comment: It looks like you’re forgetting to set data on your call to svrepdesign (Eg there is no `data=` argument